# How to create dynamic checkbox group for menu selection like Uber-eats android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-checkbox, custom-view

I want to create a custom view that can have a dynamic number of checkboxes to select, like Uber eats, or any other food ordering app. Can you please share ideas? Is it a good idea to display it as a recyclerview or listview?

[image]

Comment: listview was deprecated ages ago, use recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below way of implementation in your requirements

**in activity or fragment**

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="#FFFFFF"/>

       LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
```

**below code is for adapter class**

```
       onBindViewHolder{
       
               Model model = list.get(position);
               if (model.isSelected()) {
                   holder.imageViewSelect.setImageResource(R.mipmap.check);
               } else {
                   holder.imageViewSelect.setImageResource(R.mipmap.uncheck);
               }
       }
       
       linearCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View view) {
                           int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                           if(pos >= 0 && list != null && pos < list.size()){
                               for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
                                   Model model = list.get(i);
                                   model.setSelected(false);
                                   list.set(i,model);
                                   notifyItemChanged(i);
                               }
       
                               Model model = list.get(pos);
                               cancelReason.setSelected(true);
                               list.set(pos,model);
                               listener.selectValue(pos);
                               imageViewSelect.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.check);
                               notifyItemChanged(pos);
                           }
                       }
                   });
```

**in xml for Adapter**

```
       <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:orientation="horizontal">
       
               <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/imageView_select"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                   android:src="@mipmap/uncheck" />
       
               <TextView
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:lineSpacingExtra="3sp"
                   android:padding="@dimen/margin_padding_15"
                   android:text="Banana"
                   android:textColor="@color/black" />
       
               <TextView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:lineSpacingExtra="3sp"
                   android:padding="@dimen/margin_padding_15"
                   android:text="$200"
                   android:textColor="@color/black" />
       
           </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it should be a custom view please

Comment: Yes the code is a custom type you just need to use this way in your existing code with the list of dynamic size, only you need to pass the list of item(name,price,isselected) in adapter class and you can update the selected model on every selection you can make it for multiple selection.create one method to loop and get final selected object list in adapter class